# How to access an element of an array in Assembly?

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm

The documentation says:

> **(Index ∗ Scale) + Displacement** ⎯ This address mode offers an efficient way to index into a static array when the element size is 2,
>   4, or 8 bytes. The displacement locates the beginning of the array,
>   the index register holds the subscript of the desired array element,
>   and the processor automatically converts the subscript into an index
>   by applying the scaling factor.

Can **Base** be used instead of **Displacement** to specify the beginning of the array:

```
Base + (Index ∗ Scale)
```

Comment: Isn't A+(B\*C) equivalent to (B\*C)+A? What does it matter how you name the numbers?

Comment: Yes, `Base + (Index * Scale)` is legal. Did you try it? That picture from [my last answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44893689/error-addressing-memory-when-usingespscale/44898508#44898508) should make this pretty clear. Base, Index, and Scale are provided, while Displacement is "None".

Comment: @Cody Gray Yes I tried it and it worked, but I just thought that maybe in certain situations, it could not work.

Comment: @riodoro1 I was not asking if I could use `Displacement + (Index ∗ Scale)` instead of `(Index ∗ Scale) + Displacement`, I was asking if I can use `Base + (Index ∗ Scale)` instead of `(Index ∗ Scale) + Displacement`.

Answer (score 1):

*base, index, scale,* and *displacement* are just the names for the four parts of a memory operand. You are free to use each part for whatever purpose you like. For example, to fetch the n+k-th entry of an array, you might use something like this:

```
mov al, [array + ebx + ecx]
```

where `n` is stored in `ebx` and `k` is stored in `ecx.` In This case, the “base” is really used as an index into the array and so is the “index” part.